# Serve the lumen project after closing the terminal in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laravel-5, lumen

i am working on the lumen a framework by the Laravel. i can run the project through linux terminal by the following command

```
php artisan serve
```

the project works fine when terminal is opened but when i close the terminal the protect stop working.

Any command to run the project in the background ?

Comment: have you tried `php artisan serve &`  ?

Comment: @Mhd. Tahawi i am running this command nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon > /dev/null 2>&1 & the command runs successfully but application does not starts

Comment: if it is not starting how do you know it is running successfully , and you are sending the output to `/dev/null/ ` if there is any error messages you won't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you close the terminal, you kill the process started by it.
**NOT SURE** but maybe this could help:
`php artisan serve &`

Comment: thanx 
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon & ?
this works fine for me